# unknown protocol in curl

Tags: php, curl

I have been working this for 2 days to solve this problem. I have an error when the time I send request from my url using curl. But the problem now I get this kind of error

```
error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

I would like to know what are the possible reasons why I get this error? Hoping for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is the underlying TLS library (OpenSSL I presume) that can't figure out the proper protocol being used so it fails in negotiation. You sometimes succeed better by specifying  the specific SSL version you know the site runs, like with curl's [-2](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-2) or [-3](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-3) etc options.

Comment: I try this already. The error for -2 "OpenSSL was built without SSLV2 Support", when i used -3 the error is wrong version number.

Answer (score 0):

It seems possible that your server returns plain html, not encrypted html, on SSL port. I mean, the web server might be bound to port 443, but might not be using mod_ssl, so returning open, unencrypted content. This usually happens with misconfigured tomcat servers.

Comment: the port I used is not 443.

Comment: what is your url then? someserver.com:80 with httpS by any chance ?